# Поиск всех слов в тексте с символами испанского языка

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

Мне нужно найти все слова в тексте, в котором могут быть символы испанского алфавита. Из-за того, что в нем встречаются символы вида "á", регулярное выражение не работает, как нужно. Я пытался сделать так:

```
import re
import io


with io.open('1.txt', 'rb') as file_for_search:
    for m in re.finditer(rb'\b[\wá]+\b', file_for_search.read()):
        print(m)
```

Но возникает ошибка:

> SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters

Содержимое файла 1.txt:

```
Eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at va

ábaco
abdomen
abeja
abierto
abogado
abono
aborto
abrazo
abrir
abuelo
abuso
acabar

rus faucibus ornare
```

Результат работы скрипта (если регулярка выглядит так **rb'\b\w+\b'**):

```
<re.Match object; span=(36, 38), match=b'va'>
<re.Match object; span=(42, 43), match=b'a'>  <-- 1 часть слова
<re.Match object; span=(45, 49), match=b'baco'>  <-- 2 часть слова
<re.Match object; span=(51, 58), match=b'abdomen'>
<re.Match object; span=(60, 65), match=b'abeja'>
```

Тут одно слово разбивается на две части, что недопустимо.

Если использовать регулярку вида **r'\b[\wa-zñáéíóúü]+\b'** и читать файл в обычном режиме "r", то искомое слово отображается криво:

```
<re.Match object; span=(40, 47), match='aМЃbaco'>
```

**Подскажите регулярное выражение или способ, как решить задачу по поиску слов, в том числе и испанских.**.
При решении задачи **важно** использовать конструкцию "**for m in re.finditer**". Режим "rb" в файле НЕ обязателен, можно использовать обычный "r".

Дополнительно: было бы хорошо найти способ, с помощью которого можно искать также слова и из французского алфавита. Там тоже есть символы вида "é". А также символы японского языка:

```
あらいぐま
あらし
あらすじ
```

Comment: Почему io.open, a не просто open?

Comment: как насчет поработать с [Unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-howto)? просто предложение, не погружаясь в детали

Comment: Используйте открытие через open в режиме r и указанием кодировки (encoding="utf-8", например).

Answer (score 0):

Самый быстрый способ:

```
import string
import io

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
with io.open('111.txt', 'r') as file_for_search:
    for line in file_for_search.readlines():
        for symbol in line.strip().lower():
            if symbol not in alphabet:
                print(line)
```

Вот еще 1 способ на исключение через `finditer`

```
import re

with open('111.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        search = re.finditer(r'\w+', line.strip())
        if len(list(search)) > 1:
            print(line)
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но либо я не достаточно точно объяснил задачу, либо вы ее не так поняли: "Мне нужно найти все слова в тексте, в котором МОГУТ БЫТЬ символы испанского алфавита". То есть искать надо обычные слова, но не исключены и спецсимволы испанского алфавита.

Comment: Тогда замени alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase на список из испанского алфавита и if symbol not in alphabet: на if symbol in alphabet:

Comment: Просто не особо понятно что в твоем понимание испанские слова, это то в которых есть спец символы или слова испанского языка? 
Если символы то тут просто, если слова, то задача гораздо труднее чем есть. 
ñ ¡  ¿ é, á, ú, ó, í ü - это спец символы языка. 
А есть еще алфавит который состоит из латинских букв и без словаря всех испанских слов ты их не найдешь

Comment: Вот пример нескольких слов, про которые я пишу: puñal empresa croqueta ladrón osadía lámina ébano

Comment: empresa croqueta - а как ты хочешь определить что это испанское слово если это латиница? 
Тебе надо составлять словарь слов испанского или искать либу которая сама поймет какой язык